# Javac command works when typed manually but not when run in Makefile

Tags: java, makefile

I wish to compile my java project using a makefile as I have done previously however when I run make, it says that the command javac was not found, however if I were to type out the exact same command I am running from my Makefile in the terminal (at the same directory level) the command runs successfully.

The makefile

```
PATH = src/main/java/cs455/overlay
FILES = $(PATH)/node/*.java $(PATH)/util/*.java
all:
    javac $(FILES)
run:
    Java ProducerConsumer
clean:
    rm *.class
```

The corresponding command that is formed from make is

```
javac src/main/java/cs455/overlay/node/*.java src/main/java/cs455/overlay/util/*.java
```

Again just typing make, it says javac command not found, but pasting this above in the terminal runs no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One, you should probably use another tool for building Java projects. maven or sbt are far more common. Two, do not modify the `PATH`.

```
SRCPATH = src/main/java/cs455/overlay
FILES = $(SRCPATH)/node/*.java $(SRCPATH)/util/*.java
all:
    javac $(FILES)
run:
    Java ProducerConsumer
clean:
    rm *.class
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I will approve this as the answer as soon as SO allows me, I appreciate the help.
As for building I was initially looking at Gradle, but will consider maven now as well, I just wanted to get something running as coming from C++ makefiles are where I feel more comfortable

Comment: @Marc-9 Gradle is also very popular. I've only seen SBT used in Scala-specific projects; my own preference is Maven, but Gradle is the standard for Android.